# Code not executing

Tags: c, integer

I am solving basic C exercises. The following code, when written, failed to execute. Can anyone suggest why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 4, j = -1, k = 0, w, x, y, z;

  w = i || j || k;
  x = i && j && k;
  y = i || j && k;
  z = i && j || k;

  printf("w=%d x=%d y=%d z=%d", w, x, y, z);
  return 0;
}
```

P.S. No errors being shown, but the execution window doesn't open.

Comment: Window? This is in Visual Studio or some other IDE? I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. Maybe try starting the code by stepping into it?

Comment: possible the application did show up, but it finished fast enough to be cought?

Comment: Its working fine in ubuntu 12.04!

Comment: Maybe as standalone console app it just closes too fast - use `getchar();` before `return 0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason nothing seems to be happening is that the execution window doesn't hang around after the application terminates, and the application itself executes so quickly that you never get a chance to *see* the window before it's already gone.

One way to work around this is to insert a code that reads input before the application exits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 4, j = -1, k = 0, w, x, y, z;

  w = i || j || k;
  x = i && j && k;
  y = i || j && k;
  z = i && j || k;

  printf("w=%d x=%d y=%d z=%d", w, x, y, z);  /* You probably want \n here. */

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=4,j=-1,k=0,w,x,y,z;
    w=i||j||k;
    x=i&&j&&k;
    y=i||j&&k;
    z=i&&j||k;
    printf("w=%d x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",w,x,y,z);
    //                         ^^ Hello there.
    return 0;
}
```

Reason : stdout is line-buffered on your terminal, so nothing gets printed before you output a newline (`'\n'`).

Comment: This is not true, on Ubuntu 14.04, at least

Comment: This application exits right after the print. Of course the print will be flushed, here's no a problem.

Comment: @Gregor clarified, this was not meant as a generality.